# Getting user's contacts from Windows Live or Outlook API

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-live, microsoft-account

I would like to know is there any possibilities to export and get an user's Outlook or Microsoft Account contact list as csv file with his/her authentication using any APIs?

Thanks!

Comment: This dose exactly what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826535.aspx however Just remember you can't use these addresses for anything other than sending a single mail to them unless it's for an explicit purpose E.G so and so has invited you... however keeping the email to keep sending spam to is a big no no your not allowed to add them to a mail shot list as most system's will ban you for unsolicited spamming of users Oh and it's a breach of MS API TOS From that API you would have to create an application to build the CSV file but it is C# for Windows Store

Comment: Thank you Martin, but that links seems to be invalid!.

Comment: strange as it is working for me, Outlook.com API is page title see if this rediect's you to the correct place,
http://dev.live.com/ if so click on the outlook button